# Extracting properties from array

Tags: javascript

I have this function which takes a `json` parameter which contains an array of search objects.

```
function receiveSearch(search, json) {
    return {
        type: RECEIVE_SCHOOL_SEARCH,
        items: json.packages,
        receivedAt: Date.now(),
        search: Object.assign({}, search, { next: json.next, start: search.next }),
    };
}
```

My `json`
 property looks like:

```
>0:Object
>1:Object
>2:Object
>3:Object
...{ more }
```

I would like to return to the `search` object two properties from json i.e `name` and `suburb`. How do I do this? I would prefer to use something neat like lodash/ramda/underscore but plain js is fine.

And each object contains the following properties:

```
id:"10360"
centreId:776
name:"ABBOTSFORD"
suburb:"TARNEIT"
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to you problem using **JavaScript** could be make a new object which contains only required property and return that.

Just assume your json looks like this:

```
var x = {search:{id:"10360",centreId:776,name:"ABBOTSFORD",suburb:"TARNEIT"},otherProp:val}
```

To get required properties, you can make another function and return the object with required fields:

```
function ReturnRequiredPropertyObject(anyObj)
{
    var newObj = {};
    newObj.search = {};
    newObj.search.name = anyObj.search.name;
    newObj.search.suburb = anyObj.search.suburb;
    return newObj;
}
```

You can put the above code in loop if you are getting an array of search object.

To make the above code generic, we can do the following:

```
function ReturnRequiredPropertyObject(anyObj,requiredPropertyArray)
{
    var newObj = {};
    for(var counter = 0;counter<requiredPropertyArray.length;counter++)
    {
        newObj[requiredPropertyArray[counter]] = anyObj[requiredPropertyArray[counter]];

    }
    return newObj;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok resolved.

Answer [is](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/855)

```
_.map(json,_.partialRight(_.pick,['name','suburb']));
```